# VSCode Custom Python Debug Command

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

### Description

I have been using VSCode for a while now. Currently, the Code Runner extension enables me to run Python scripts, using custom commands. However, I would like to know if VSCode is able to perform additional actions, compared to the Code Runner extension, which just runs my custom command `pipenv run python -u {open_file_path}`.

### Goal

I currently use pipenv for my Python projects. I would like VSCode to launch a pipenv shell and execute a couple of commands to run my Python scripts.

Here are the steps I hope VSCode is able to automate when pressing `F5` to start debugging.

1. Launch a pipenv shell if one is not already launched.

   ```
   pipenv shell
   ```
2. Change directory to code source directory.

   ```
   cd {project_root/src}
   ```
3. Run the script inside the pipenv shell.

   ```
   python {open_file_path}
   ```

I have read that the `launch.json` is able to run `preLaunchTask`. It seems that it could resolve point one of launching `pipenv shell`. I am still trying to figure out how this works.

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated.

### Platform / Version

- **Platform**: Windows 10
- **Python Version**: 3.9.9
- **Pipenv Version**: 2021.5.29
- **VSCode Version**: 1.62.3
- **VSCode Microsft Python Extensions Enabled**: Yes